# How to SET CELL VALUE without written any formula in it

Tags: google-sheets, google-query-language

I have values in

- A2 = "2"
- B2 = "1"
- C2 = "3"
- and formula in D2

Is it possible to set a value of Cell A3 equals to C2 without putting any formula in A3 and depending upon results of D2 and not using app script?
Like if:

- D2 = if(A2>B2,than value A3= C2 eles keep blank

Answer (score 0):

no, it's not possible without formula & without script. the formula would be:

```
=IF(A2 > B2, C2, )
```

[image]

however, you can add a column to the left of **A** column and then put this formula in **A3** cell:

```
={"", IF(B2 > C2, D2, )}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for yours reply and You are right, actually my problem is something like this , 
1) Sheet 1 is for scrapeing  data from web in range B5:H on every 5 minutes and this entry can vary from 1 row to 50 or more 
2) A5: A is with formula = if(B5>0, now(),"") 
3) consider currently B5:H10 is filled with data
3) if copying data by app script from sheet 1 and pasting in  sheet2 after last row, this adding many blanco row's in sheet2  due to formula in column A5:A on  sheet1
4) wants tp copy just from sheet1 A:5 to till last row of column sheet1 H column to avoid blank rows

Comment: @raj sheet is private

Comment: Now sheet is as per discribed problame and its public

Comment: Guru somehow i managed with filter by removing blanks but it's adding much more rows into sheet main that can Slow Down speed

Comment: Guru I would like to thank you because of you I tried a lot and got solution, not able to post code because I am doing this work on phone not on computer

Comment: glad to hear that. you also have an answer on https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/125178/skip-empty-rows-while-copying

Comment: Thanks for yours reply , what about table scraping any success ?

Answer (score 0):

For (almost?) all practical purposes "can't be done" but as a curiosity, and perhaps with some liberal interpretation of the requirements (and because tagged [google-query-language](/questions/tagged/google-query-language)), it might be considered technically feasible (if largely useless). Assuming the 'trigger' is for the formula in D2 to return `9`, in A2 with A3 blank:

```
=query(C2:D2,"select C where D=9 label C '2'")
```